# Real world social network datasets with ground-truth non-overlapping community structure

Tags: data-request, network-structure

I am looking for social network datasets which have got non-overlapping community structure preferably ground-truth otherwise would also suffice. I need it for my research work. I could find some on http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html but they have got overlapping community structure. Please any suggestions??

Comment: Check http://economics.mit.edu/faculty/eduflo/social and http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2293 . The authors may be able to share the data.

Comment: Thanks Anton, but this is not what I am looking for.